# Passing variables with jquery ui tabs with select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I'm using tabs for an application that contains form elements on each of them. When the user navigates to a different tab, and the fields were modified, a hidden variable "IsDirty" is being set.

When I implement the beforeActivate event on tabs ... I do a check if any value has changed and set a hidden variable as "IsDirty", I do this in the beforeActivate as you have access to the Old and New tab, eg:

```
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        ...
        $panel_Old.find("input#hdIsDirty").val('0');
        $tabs.tabs('select', $tab_New.index());
        $panel_Old.find("input#hdIsDirty").val('1');
        ...
     },
```

I then implement the select event too eg:

```
     select: function (event, ui) {
         // other code here
     }
```

My question is ... in the beforeActivate event ... when I call

```
    $tabs.tabs('select', $tab_New.index());
```

can I pass some parameters eg ... previous tab ... that the select event would have as custom arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't pass custom arguments to an event unless you modify the widget itself.

What you **can** do, if you wish, is set an attribute to the widget in your event, and then retrieve them later:

```
beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    ...

    $(this).attr('data-oldtab', $tab_Old.index()); // or whatever information you want

    $panel_Old.find("input#hdIsDirty").val('0');
    $tabs.tabs('select', $tab_New.index());
    $panel_Old.find("input#hdIsDirty").val('1');
    ...
 },
```

Then, when binding `select`:

```
 select: function (event, ui) {
     oldtabindex = $(this).data('oldtab');
     // other code here
 }
```

For more information on `data()` please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/).